# [RAILS]: stripe connect. Invalid Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, stripe-payments

I developped a rails app using Stripe Connect.
When a user create an account (using devise), he is redirected_to the account setting page with my  my stripe button (connecting to the stripe connect account). 
When my user click on this button he has the following error:
Invalid request. Hint: check the encoding for your request parameters and URL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/percent-encoding). For assistance, email support@stripe.com.
Is there someone who encountered this problem before? and what is the solution?
Thks in advance
Here is my Reservation controller code:

```
    def charge(room, reservation)
      if !reservation.user.stripe_id.blank?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(reservation.user.stripe_id)
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          :customer => customer.id,
          :amount => reservation.total * 100,
          :description => room.listing_name,
          :currency => "eur",
          :destination => {
            :amount => reservation.total * 80, # 80% of the total amount goes to the Host
            :account => room.user.merchant_id # Host's Stripe customer ID
          }
        )

        if charge
          reservation.Approved!
          send_sms(room, reservation) if room.user.setting.enable_sms
          flash[:notice] = "Reservation created successfully!"
        else
          reservation.Declined!
          flash[:alert] = "Cannot charge with this payment method!"
        end
      end
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      reservation.declined!
      flash[:alert] = e.message
    end
```

Comment: Did you add client and api key in intializer ?

Comment: Yes  `Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]`

Comment: Can you replace your rescue to look like this ?
`rescue Stripe::CardError, Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  flash[:error]= e.message
  redirect_to root_url
end`

Also please share the logs.

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: I don't see any error in my app and in my logs, since the message (Invalid request. Hint: check the encoding for your request parameters and URL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/percent-encoding). For assistance, email support@stripe.com. )  is outside my app, on the redirect page: https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id= ...........

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something on how devise works but this code does not seem to have any link with the error, no? The error message seems to imply the link you generated for the Connect button is incorrect.

Comment: Well I got it The problem came from my helper url which did not understand the client id. My url was including the client id this way: http://stripe....<%= ENV['STRIPE_CA_ID %>....and that was wrong. The solution was to include the ca_id directly in the url!